# Can someone explain the =~ operator in logstash?

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

The following filter **fails with**: *The given configuration is invalid. Reason: Expected one of /, /, any character at line 23, column 1 (byte 308)* because there is a "/" missing at the end. It has to be **/path/**. Seems logstash interprets everything after /path as part of the regexp if not terminated with "/".

```
filter {
    if [message] =~ /path {
        drop { }
    }
}
```

1. I know /path/ is a regexp, but what are the forward slashes for in this case?
2. Will my pattern match any log line that has /path in it?

Couldn't find anything in the [official docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html) unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

What's between the two `/` is the pattern and the `/` are just delimiters, separating the pattern from the rest of the configuration.

So if you have `[message] =~ /path/`, it will check if the field messages contains the string `path`. To match `/path`, you'll need to use `/\/path/`.

Comment: Thx. Is that written down anywhere?

Comment: @kev Not explicitly. But I might have seen a few example of logstash configuration, so I think I understood it there. Also the way of writing the regex patterns between `/` exists elsewhere (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Delimiters, it is used with sed and maybe others).